# React JSX check if async function return true or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a component, I've implemented a function call that has a promised call and returns either `true` or `false`. I'm using the call for conditional rendering like below:

```
return (
  isAuthValid() ? <div>Authenticated</div> : </div>Invalid User</div>
)
```

`isAuthValid` has a Rest Call like below:

```
async function isAuthValid(){
 const response = await getAuth(); 
 // response.data return boolean value (true or false)
 return response.data;
}
```

I'm receiving `Promise {<pending>}` from `isAuthValid` execution instead of boolean value.
I can do it with assigning and updating `state` as well.

e.g

```
const {auth, setAuth} = React.useState(false);

 async function isAuthValid(){
  const response = await getAuth(); 
  setAuth(response.data)
 }

return (
 auth ? <div>Authenticated</div> : </div>Invalid User</div>
)
```

I'm trying to understand why direct execution doesn't work. I've implemented `async-await` to make it asynchronous. How to make it work like that without using the state hook?

Comment: Async functions always return a promise in js.  You have to wait for the promise to get resolved or rejected. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: you should always separate fetching data and displaying data. There are no other way to do it without setting state.

Comment: @OdaYukimura So it means, React JSX got `pending promise` call and since there are no hooks to trigger `re-rendering`, It doesn't render changes. I got it.. thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that this code fires when you load your component. You can use the useEffect hook to do this, and pass in an empty array of dependencies so it only runs once.

I switched from async/await into a promise just because they're a little easier for me to get my head around.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import getAuth from "./get-auth";

function MyComponent() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    getAuth()
    .then(response => {
       setAuth(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
      // If error, let's set their auth to false.
      setAuth(response.data)
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    auth ? Authenticated : Invalid User
  );
}
```

Comment: `useState` returns an array: `const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(false);`

Comment: That's what I get for being tired. Edited and thank you!

Comment: My question is different, I also mentioned that I can do it easily with `state` hook. I was just trying to understand why direct call assignment is not working.

Comment: The way React implements state isn't designed to work with direct async calls, async functions are considered side effects that should be handled in the useEffect hook when using functional components, or componentWillMount/componentWillUpdate methods in class components.